# JBoss 6.4.20.0 installation in windows

Tags: jboss-eap-6

I want to install/use **JBoss 6.4.20.0** in my windows machine.Could you please suggest where I can download it.

Is there any support available for this product.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are developer, you can download and use JBoss EAP for development purposes for free through the Red Hat Developer program:

https://developers.redhat.com/products/eap/download/

There are downloads for older versions there, too.

EAP 6.4 is still supported by Red Hat, but you must have a subscription to receive support.